# Remote codeSign using Xcode

Tags: macos, certificate, code-signing, codesign

I've placed my developer certificate in remote server so that it will be safe and every authorised developer (with proper ssl key) may auto sign the app within the build part.

This certificate reside on a special keychain file on the server.

I added post compilation script to my Xcode project that use 'scp' to copy my target to the remote server, sign it remotely, and return the signed result. here's what my script does :

```
1. scp <my_target> <user>@<server>:
2. /tmp/ssh <user>@<server> 'security unlock-keychain -p <password> \
    <home>/Library/Keychains/login.keychain; codesign -f -s " \
    <my_signature>" /tmp/<my_target>'
3. scp <user>@<server>:/tmp/<my_target> .
```

The problem is that on every ssh session, I need to unlock the keychain file, and provide password to do so, which is unsafe (see stage 2 on my script). Perhaps is there's a simple way to avoid it by keeping the ad-hoc keychain open.

I also wonder if Xcode have inherited remote signing capabilities, that replace my script. I'd rather use built-in method than "inventing the wheel".

Comment: Best not to cross post. http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/249644/revisions